# gousb Cross compile from MacOS to Windows

Tags: go, cross-compiling, libusb

I'm using the gousb package to print to a USB POS printer. It works great on MacOS. I need to cross-compile to Windows 10. Gousb is written in C so cross-compile requires gcc. I've got everything installed but I get an error that I don't know how to fix.

I installed libusb-1, gcc, and mingw-w64 using homebrew.

Here is the command I run:
`GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -o bin/fsrestposprint/fsrestpostprint.exe main.go`

I get this response:
`github.com/google/gousb`
`/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/8.0.0/toolchain-i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.23/lib/libusb-1.0.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you run `file /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.23/lib/libusb-1.0.a`, what `file` would report? I'm asking because `.a` is a library file (a bunch of `.o` files lumped together by the `ar` (*ar*chive) tool), and since you're cross-compiling to `i686`, these `.o` files are supposed to be for the matching arch (not `i386` or something else). Or it just may be corrupted for some reason.

Comment: The command gives this response: `/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.23/lib/libusb-1.0.a: current ar archive random library`

Comment: OK, let's look at the files. First you do `ar t /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.23/lib/libusb-1.0.a` — it prints you the names of the `.o` files it contains, then pick any `.o` file, let's say it's `libusb_1_0_la-core.o`, and do `ar p /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.23/lib/libusb-1.0.a libusb_1_0_la-core.o >foo.o`; and now run `file foo.o`—this time it shoule tell you the architecture of the file—say, on my Linux/amd64 system I get `foo.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`.